# Recall selected value of a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to recall a selected value of a drop down box after my servlet has ran the query on my database.

There is no limit on variables so i have used `c:foreach` to populate the drop-down.

The code is as follows

```js
function moduleLookup() {
  var trainId = document.getElementById("Selector").value;
  document.trainForm.trainId.value = trainId;
  document.trainForm.submit();
}
```

```html
<select id="Selector" onchange="moduleLookup()" onchange=storeValues()>
  <option value="/javaTrainingServletProject/UserAdministration?id=0">Select module</option>
  <option value="0">All Modules</option>
  <c:forEach items="${modules}" var="module">
    <option value="${module.id}">${module.title }</option>
  </c:forEach>


</select>
```

I have tried every method I can find to get the refreshed drop down to have the previously selected value. I have tried to add cookie data but, I am new to jquery.

Comment: Instead of the value, store the [*options.selectedIndex*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-select-selectedindex), then set the same option to selected later.

Comment: `c:forEach` is not valid HTML, so there's something missing from this question...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan isn't that (old) Angular?

Comment: @Dura: I have no idea, hence the comment :). If it is Angular, the Angular tag should be added. The OP also mentions servlets, so it could be JSP, but again, not sure. The current code doesn't seem to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the listener, you can pass a reference to the element using *this*:

```
<select id="Selector" onchange="moduleLookup(this)" ...>
```

Then in the function you can do:

```
function moduleLookup(select) {
  var trainId = select.value;
  ...
}
```

Note also that to be successful (and hence be submitted with the form), a form control must have a name. The select element only has an id (which should be redundant now, so make it a name).

If you want to restore the selected value, you can store the [*selectedIndex*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-select-selectedindex) and restore that later. If you are submitting the form, the page will refresh so perhaps you can just set the appropriate option's [selected attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-option-selected) when generating the HTML.